# Display local .svg file in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way to display local .svg files in Google chrome? I was able to do this under Windows 7 but I just made a clean install of Windows 8 and Google Chrome and I cannot anymore display .svg files that are stored in my computer's file system. Whenever trying to open a local .svg file I just get a message saying that "This File can harm your computer" and asking me if I want to download the file.

This is really a problem for me as I want to use chrome to browse a local HTML report (generated by some software package) that contains embedded .svg files. Not being able to display the .svg files in chrome reduces considerably the usability of the reports. To make matters worse, I am having the same problem with Firefox. The only browser that seems to be able to display local .svg files is Internet Explorer...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Chrome Version: 26.0.1410.64

Operating System: Windows 8

Extensions: Google docs, Kippt, Pocket